# Conditional probability statement formulation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X,Y$ and a difficult strictly increasing function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$. I need the probability 
$$
P(|X|<f(|Y|)) > 0,
$$
but this is an awful expression and impossible to check because of the nature of $f$. So instead I want to say something stronger in the sense of, no matter what the value of $Y$ is, the probability that $X$ is arbitrarily small is bigger than zero. I believe this can done formally by using a statement concerning conditional probabilities. Can someone help me to formally formulate this statement?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the function in question? Maybe it's not that bad?

Comment: You might try something like $$\{|X|<\epsilon,|Y|>\alpha\}\subseteq\{|X|<f(|Y|)\}$$ if $\alpha$ is chosen large enough to guarantee that $f(\alpha)>\epsilon$, thus, **if $X$ and $Y$ are independent**, $$P(|X|<f(|Y|))\geqslant P(|X|<\epsilon,|Y|>\alpha)=P(|X|<\epsilon)P(|Y|>\alpha)$$ and if the RHS is positive, you are done.

Comment: With no independence, use $$P(|X|<f(|Y|))\geqslant \int_{\alpha}^\infty P(|X|<\epsilon\mid |Y|=y)dP_{|Y|}(y)$$ and finish as before provided $$P(|X|<\epsilon\mid |Y|=y)>0$$ for every $y$ and $$P(|Y|>\alpha)>0$$

Comment: Great, many thanks. With this I will get what I want.